# how to increase output quality from html2canvas : angular

Tags: javascript, angular, html2canvas

I have implemented html2canvas in my angular project, but whenever I am converting the html element to image, it converting but the output quality is poor. Is there any way to increase the quality?

Any kind of help would be appreciated. here is the code that I am using.

```
convertHtmlToImage(){
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("imageBlock"))
    .then((canvas) => {
      let image = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.9);
      console.log(image);
    })  
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
 }
```

Comment: did you find any solution?